# How do you test for trend in a generalized linear model, particularly for odd numbers of levels of a variable?

Tags: regression, sas, categorical-encoding

I'm trying to test for a trend across levels of a categorical variable using a contrast statement in a model and can not figure out how to do it when there are odd numbers of levels.  Looking at SAS's support page for contrast statements (ie http://support.sas.com/kb/22/912.html) it's easy to set up for even numbers of levels using coefficients balanced around 0, but when you have an odd number the value in the middle would be assigned the coefficient 0, meaning it would not be counted in the contrast at all.  I've contacted SAS support directly and they suggested I ask on a statistical forum such as this.

Comment: A useful discussion by Jeanette Mumford appears at http://mumford.bol.ucla.edu/lin_cont_illus.pdf .