# How do you test for a trend in a series of random variables?

Tags: regression, ordinal-data, ranking

If I want to test whether black mice are heavier than white mice it's pretty easy to set up a t-test where I'm comparing the mean weights of a bunch of mice, but if I wanted to test whether black mice are heavier than gray mice, which are heavier than white mice, is there a way to do it?  Particularly without requiring any assumptions about the nature of the trend I'm looking for (ie it doesn't have to be linear, just X>Y>Z)?

I'm imagining some sort of trend statistic similar to a Spearman's correlation coefficient where instead of two continuous measurements I'm comparing the hypothesized ranks of the means to the actual ranks of the means, using the standard errors of the respective means for inference, but I don't know if this exists or if there is a better way to do it. I'd also like this to be generalizable enough that I could compare parameter estimates from a more complicated model, and I've asked a similar question before that was much more specific to this situation ([How do you test for trend in a generalized linear model, particularly for odd numbers of levels of a variable?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112940/how-do-you-test-for-trend-in-a-generalized-linear-model-particularly-for-odd-nu)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to reshape the data to "long" format, i.e. stacking the values of X, Y, Z into one variable (let's call it "Value") and then distinguishing values from X, Y or Z by a second variable "Group" with values 1 (=Z), 2 (=Y) and 3 (=X). Then you check if the lower confidence bound associated with Kendall's rank correlation between "Group" and "Value" is larger than 0. This trend test is equivalent to the one-sided Jonckheere-Terpstra-Test.

The tricky thing with a more general modelling approach is the fact that you are particularly interested in effect tests of ordered factors, which is generally not so easy.

Comment: The Jonckheere test is what I was looking for, I'd never heard of it before, thanks! I can work from there to try to get a more generalizable methods.